# How to get CandidateID from SuccessFactors Career (recruitment) site?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-successfactors

I'm trying to build a Fiori application (sapui5) and it is deployed, working through link. My problem is: I have to put it on a recruitment site, the Career Opportunities site (it is somehow connected to SAP Successfactors), and I am supposed to know the person's CandidateID because my app is based on that. 
So when somebody applying for a job in Career Opportunities site, and clicks on "Next" (after filling in the fields), they get to a site where there are some information and my link. When they click on the link, I should get their candidateId to my link. 
How could I get that? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

The Information of all candidates can be retrieved via OData API. 
The site you are referring to is probably a career site builder page. Within SFSF this pages can be adapted with standard elements how the page should look like. 
One element is the custom Javascript plugin where you are quite free in what you are doing.
Unfortunately I doubt that you can compose a link containing the candidate ID without doing some heavy stuff you should NOT do like reading the URL and extracting the candidate ID or something like this.

Long answer short: it might be possible technically but you really should avoid it, also in terms of security - it also sounds like you do not really know the system where your link magically appears. So: don’t do it :)